# C# - Effeciently writing code

Tags: c#

I am pasting my code snippet below. Could some body suggest a better and effecient way of writing this. I would like minimum code to be written and avoid repetition.

```
private void SetControlVisibility()
{

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetsBasicById") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetDetailsByIds"))
    {
        Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)";
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = false;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetsBasicBySedols") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetDetailsBySedols"))
    {
        Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440,0003496)";
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = false;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportByIds"))
    {
        Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1:100)";
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = true;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportBySedol"))
    {
        Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440:100)";
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = true;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `switch (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)`

Comment: as above but store the DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text into a string and check if its null before switching

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My alternate code:

```
private void SetControlVisibility()
{
    string resultText;
    bool b = false;

    switch (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        case "GetAssetsBasicById":
        case "GetAssetDetailsByIds":
            b = true;
            resultText = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)";
            break;

        case "GetAssetsBasicBySedols":
        case "GetAssetDetailsBySedols":
            b = true;
            resultText = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440,0003496)";
            break;

        case "GetInvestmentReportByIds":
        resultText = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1:100)";
            break;

        case "GetInvestmentReportBySedol":
        resultText = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440:100)";
            break;

        default: return;
    }

    chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = !b;
    chkPublishXML.Visible = b;
    Label2.Text = resultText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary to avoid both nested if's and switch/cases:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, bool, bool>> _dropDownMap = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, bool, bool>>
{
    {"GetAssetsBasicById", new Tuple<string, bool, bool>("(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)", false, true) },
    {"GetAssetDetailsByIds", new Tuple<string, bool, bool>("(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)", false, true) },
    ...
};

private void SetControlVisibility()
{
    var mapping = _dropDownMap[DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text];
    if (mapping != null)
    {
        Label2.Text = mapping.Item1;
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = mapping.Item2;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = mapping.Item3;
    }
}
```

If you favour readability over small code, then the `Tuple` could be replaced by an explicit VO class:

```
private class DropDownMappings
{
    public DropDownMappings(label, excludeMAPFundsVisible, publishXMLVisible)
    {
        Label2Text = label;
        ExcludeMAPFundsVisible = excludeMAPFundsVisible;
        PublishXMLVisible = publishXMLVisible;
    }
    public string Label2Text { get; set; }
    public bool ExcludeMAPFundsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool PublishXMLVisible { get; set; }
}

private readonly Dictionary<string, DropDownMappings> _dropDownMap = new Dictionary<string, DropDownMappings>
{
    {"GetAssetsBasicById", new DropDownMappings("(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)", false, true) },
    {"GetAssetDetailsByIds", new DropDownMappings("(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)", false, true) },
    ...
};

private void SetControlVisibility()
{
    var mapping = _dropDownMap[DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text];
    if (mapping != null)
    {
        Label2.Text = mapping.Label2Text;
        chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = mapping.ExcludeMAPFundsVisible;
        chkPublishXML.Visible = mapping.PublishXMLVisible;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to add a func, to make it more clean implementation along with null check

Comment: @Karan, it needs to be used with care though, as `Item`, `Item2` etc reduce readability. In this case that is probably OK as the code ends up small enough to relate the tuple's fields to the data. In larger solutions though, explicit data types can help. As the tuple example is probably better here, I've swapped the two examples around.

Comment: I agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate code with switch:

```
private void SetControlVisibility()
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        switch (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
        {
            case "GetAssetsBasicById":
            case "GetAssetDetailsByIds":
                Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)";
                chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = false;
                chkPublishXML.Visible = true;
                break;

            case "GetAssetsBasicBySedols":
            case "GetAssetDetailsBySedols":
                Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440,0003496)";
                chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = false;
                chkPublishXML.Visible = true;
                break;

            case "GetInvestmentReportByIds":
                Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1:100)";
                chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = true;
                chkPublishXML.Visible = false;
                break;

            case "GetInvestmentReportBySedol":
                Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440:100)";
                chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = true;
                chkPublishXML.Visible = false;
                break;

            default:
                // we do it wrong :(
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is using Item's `Tag` property with predefined enum values.

Comment: Nice and clean, +1 (and for the default comment, raised a smile!)

Comment: I still feel there is repetition of code with respect to setting the visibility of the checkboxes

Comment: @Tom so.. take inspiration from the post and further it with your own additions?

Comment: @Tom, another solution, as I wrote, is using Tag, but I don't know how you create dropdown items. Can you post code ot dropdown initialization?

Comment: I would extract the above code into another method to keep it clean

Answer (score -1):

First, taking the chks out of the `if` and using the `?:` operator will shorthand their notation.

Then, due to having only one statement inside each `if` - `else if`, brackets can be erased.

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetsBasicById") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetDetailsByIds"))
    Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1,2)";
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetsBasicBySedols") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetAssetDetailsBySedols"))
    Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440,0003496)";
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportByIds"))
    Label2.Text = "(Please enter asset ids for e.g. 1:100)";
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportBySedol"))
    Label2.Text = "(Please enter sedols for e.g. B1YW440:100)";

chkExcludeMAPFunds.Visible = (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportByIds") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportBySedol") ? true : false;

chkPublishXML.Visible = (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportByIds") || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("GetInvestmentReportBySedol") ? false : true;
```

This way, we have got rid of many lines.

Comment: Why have I been downVoted twice? At least it would be good to know what is wrong about my coding style. @General-Doomer